Next JS fetch error from Ruby - Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)
I have a Next Js app running in gogle cloud run and backend services in ruby on rails runnning on GKE i have correctly exposed the endpoints and they can connect however when i run the service on cloud run i get this error
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).


when i run the service on vercel it works fine
I ran the frontend service on vercel and it works , however when i run it on cloud run or GKE it does not work

you run request to /undefined/assignments, but probably must send to /some-id/assignments

hi @AntonBogdanov we want to fetch all assignments not just one.  it works fine on vercel but not on GCP setups

what url do you need to call? and what url do you call on the screenshot?
